# What git merge strategy I should use in my case

Tags: git, merge

I would like to merge two branchs which has the same File

**Branch Master :**

*File*

```
var1=50
var2=30
```

I create the following branch from the branch master with *`"git checkout -b dev"`*

**Branch Dev :**

*File*

```
var1=0
var2=0
var3=60
```

After merging I would like to have :

*File*

```
var1=50
var2=30
var3=60
```

When conflict I would like to keep the master changes, I have tried both :

- `git merge -s ours dev` which doesn't take any of the branch dev modifications.
- `git merge -s recursive -X ours dev` which doesn't erase the master modifications.

Is there any way to do this with **sdiff** or **diff** or any other command in Unix ?

Answer (score 0):

This is not how it works, commit on `dev` branch in that steps will be newer so GIT assumes **no conflict** you based your `dev` branch changes on `master` state. So `master` branch commit is parent of `dev` changes.

Now if you would add another commit that is not parent of `dev` branch commits it would be different. So you would need to do something like and commit it on `master`:

```
var1 = 50
var2 = 30
```

Then GIT will not assume `dev` branch changes are not conflicting, because you have some other changes in `master` as well.

Conclusion is you have to do it manually, cherry picking or reseting state of specific lines and commiting them again. Merge is not going to do it for you magically.